# Why PlotLegend is an unknown option in Mathematica 6.0?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to have a `PlotLegend` in the top-right corner of the plot, but this option does not work.

How can I add `PlotLegend` into my `Plot`? Should I buy Mathematica 8?

```
u=Sech[x];
w=Cos[x];
v=Sin[x]^2;

Plot[{u,w,v},{x,-5,5},PlotStyle->{Automatic,Dashed,DotDashed},
    PlotLegend->{"Sech[x]","Cos[x]","Sin[x]"}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PlotLegend` has always (at least since 2.2) been loaded through an add-on package.

Upgrade if you want, but loading legends using `` Needs["PlotLegends`"] `` should do the trick.

Comment: By using your trick my problem was solved, (Thank you so much),but I have this Problem with PlotMarkers too, Should I use Needs["PlotLegends`","PlotMarkers`"]? And how can I have Dot And DotDashed lines as plotMarkers in my PlotLegend? I mean something like PlotMarkers->{"--","..","-","."}

Comment: @user1436011 this is a separate question. You might be better off asking at the dedicated Mathematica StackExchange site, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/